# NSArray construction causing app crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

My app crashed, is this correctly constructed?

```
NSArray *array = [mapView.annotations  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self isKindOfClass: %@)", [MapLocation class]]];
if (array != nil)
{
    annotation = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I see that array isn't nil but it has 0 objects (on debug).   Is correctly constructed?

Comment: hmmm.... then use [array count]>0 condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSArray will raise an exception if you access something out of its bound. If the array is empty, accessing element at index 0 is out of its bound.
You can check if the array contains elements by calling `[array count]` eg:

```
NSArray *array = [mapView.annotations  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self isKindOfClass: %@)", [MapLocation class]]];
if([array count] > 0) // No need to check if the array is != NULL, the runtime won't send messages to NULL
{
    annotation = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```